# How to import bootstrap.css in sails.js

Tags: node.js, sails.js

What is the best way to include bootstrap.css in my sails.js project?  I have installed the bootstrap npm package.

`npm install bootstrap@3`

I believe I am suppose to import that in `assets/styles/importer.less` but have yet to get it working.

Comment: how did you approached? did you get anything better than getting recourses to assets?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you may have to use Grunt to compile the less, try running

`npm install` - just to make sure all the dependencies are pulled in

and then run

`grunt` - to build the assets

http://sailsjs.org/documentation/concepts/assets/default-tasks#?less

https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-less

https://github.com/WebDevStudios/CLI-Cheat-Sheet/blob/master/grunt-commands.md